# Magento After Patch 9767 product not added in wishlist

Tags: magento-1.9

I am facing issue adding product in wishlist (magento version 1.9.2.4).

Here is scenario,

Step 1 :- Make sure customer not logged in.

Step 2 :- Go to product list page and click "Add to wishlist"

Step 3 :- it will redirected to login page.

Step 4 :- Now you can check product not added in wishlist.

I have traced patch files and found issue

SUPEE-9767-1.9.2.4\app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Session.php

```
public function setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer)
{

$this->setCustomer($customer);
$this->renewSession();
// if we comment following line its working fine
//Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->renewFormKey();
Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_login', array('customer'=>$customer));
return $this;
}
```

But its not correct solution for it.

Please give better solution than above code.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm so sorry for cannot add a comment. However, with Tim's solution. An new issue is raised when customer still not login yet, the customer add product to cart and click checkout. Then, customer must login to continue checkout and it will be redirected after to wishlist page after login.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/133625)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/133625)

Answer (score 0):

I was provided a custom patch from Magento for this issue, that fixes it for EE 1.14.  The only change that I think would be necessary is taking out the check for Enterprise_Pagecache, which I have done in the code below.

The solution is to add an event observer in a local module like the following:

```
// Model/Observer.php
...
public function replaceFormKeyForWishlistAdd(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{

    $formKey = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();

    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    $beforeWishlistRequest = $session->getBeforeWishlistRequest();

    $beforeWishlistRequest['form_key'] = $formKey;
    $session->setBeforeWishlistRequest($beforeWishlistRequest);

    $newBeforeAuthUrl = Mage::getUrl('wishlist/index/add',
        array('product' => $beforeWishlistRequest['product'], 'form_key' => $formKey)
    );
    $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($newBeforeAuthUrl);
    return $this;
}
...
```

.

```
// etc/config.xml
...
<events>
    <customer_login>
        <observers>
            <namespace_module>
                <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
                <method>replaceFormKeyForWishlistAdd</method>
            </namespace_module>
        </observers>
    </customer_login>
</events>
...
```

Here is the patch, which makes these changes in the core: https://github.com/timciep/magento-tools/tree/master/Patches/SUPEE-10123_EE_1.14.0.1_v1.

Comment: Its not worked for me after adding your code wish list issue fixed but raised new issue if you create new customer it will redirect you to wish list page instead of customer dashboard same with login customer

Comment: @shyam please check your admin setting at `Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Login Options > Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in`.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing issue adding product in wishlist (magento version 2.2.3).

Here is scenario,

Step 1 :- Make sure customer not logged in.

Step 2 :- Go to product list page and click "Add to wishlist"

Step 3 :- it will redirected to login page.

Step 4 :- Now you can check product not added in wishlist.