# Product didn't added to wishlist after PATCH_SUPEE-9767 installed in version 1.9.2.1

Tags: wishlist, magento-1.9.2.1, supee-9767

I have added a product to the wishlist in following method **(Magento Version 1.9.2.1)**

**1. Without login, click on "Add to wishlist" link in any product**

**2. Get redirected to Checkout login page**

**3. Enter user name password**

**4. Redirected to the particular user's Wishlist**

Before installed the PATCH_SUPEE-9767, It worked. After Patched the product didn't added to wishlist.

Answer (score 1):

I was provided a custom patch from Magento for this issue, that fixes it for EE 1.14.  The only change that I think would be necessary is taking out the check for Enterprise_Pagecache, which I have done in the code below.

The solution is to add an event observer in a local module like the following:

```
// Model/Observer.php
...
public function replaceFormKeyForWishlistAdd(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{

    $formKey = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();

    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    $beforeWishlistRequest = $session->getBeforeWishlistRequest();

    $beforeWishlistRequest['form_key'] = $formKey;
    $session->setBeforeWishlistRequest($beforeWishlistRequest);

    $newBeforeAuthUrl = Mage::getUrl('wishlist/index/add',
        array('product' => $beforeWishlistRequest['product'], 'form_key' => $formKey)
    );
    $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($newBeforeAuthUrl);
    return $this;
}
...
```

.

```
// etc/config.xml
...
<events>
    <customer_login>
        <observers>
            <namespace_module>
                <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
                <method>replaceFormKeyForWishlistAdd</method>
            </namespace_module>
        </observers>
    </customer_login>
</events>
...
```

Here is the patch, which makes these changes in the core: https://github.com/timciep/magento-tools/tree/master/Patches/SUPEE-10123_EE_1.14.0.1_v1.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Maybe there should have a condition for the existence of $beforeWishlistRequest otherwise some Notice "undefined index" will be raised when the user logged in without adding a product to wishlist.

Answer (score 0):

PATCH_SUPEE-9767 is only about formkey in checkout. I think it will not disturb your wishlist. Some files of 9767 may override your customised files. Please re-check the patch files again

Comment: This PATCH I have done in Default Magento and tested. There are no Customized files I used. The PATCHES I have done as following order             
6788, 7405, 7405 V 1.1, 9767

Comment: do you have backup of code and database before applying patch

Comment: if you have backup, instead of applying patches please do upgrade to latest version from downloader. This will help you

Comment: Did you install 8788 Patch?

Comment: Yes, I have installed the 8788 Patch too.  Still not working

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179161/magento-after-patch-9767-product-not-added-in-wishlist - **Please check this task**